# Rails: Creating one model for each has_one association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a new model `settings` that has a foreign key to another model `school`, where many `schools` already exist. `settings belongs_to school` and `school has_one setting`. How would I make one `setting` for each existing `school` all at once?

Comment: You would iterate over your schools, and create a `settings` object for each one. It's not really clear what more you're asking here.

Comment: @meagar would i do this in a migration? sort of confused on where i would be doing this

Comment: You could, yes. You could also do it using `rails console` or you could lazily create a new `setting` for a school on first access.

Comment: @meagar how would i do this in a migration?

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is to set up default settings for existing schools with no settings ?

You can do something like :

```
School.all.each do |s|
  unless s.settings.present? 
    s.settings.new(your default settings here for each field of settings)
    s.settings.save
  end
end
```

I am iterating over every school but there is probably a method to grab only the schools without settings.

You can run it in console. (do it locally first though)